# Pick specific header messages using activemq,camel selectors from queue

Tags: jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic, custom-headers

How to consume specific header messages from queue. I am using camel activemq.

routebuilder:

```
.....
    from("activemq:Q1").
      .setHeader("myHeader",xpath(...))
          .to("activemq:Q2")
.....
```

and I trying to consume those messages which has the specific header in another class something like.

```
....
ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate = camelContext.createConsumerTemplate();
Exchange exchange = consumerTemplate.receive("activemq:Q2",10000);

String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
String customvalue = exchange.getIn().getHeader("myHeader", String.class);
.....
```

How can I get only those messages which has myHeader=123.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JMS message selectors. In the Camel consumer endpoint you can use the `selector` option: http://camel.apache.org/jms

Something a long the lines of

```
Exchange exchange = consumerTemplate.receive("activemq:Q2?selector=myHeader",10000);
```

Though I can't remember if the name of the header is enough or you would need to do

```
Exchange exchange = consumerTemplate.receive("activemq:Q2?selector=myHeader %3D '*'",10000);
```

Where %3D is `=` encoded.